# WebView: некорректное отображение страницы

Tags: java, android, webview

Решил поиграться с webView, возникли вопросы по отображениям некоторых сайтов.

В мобильном Chrome страница нормально отображается, а в приложении через webView страница имеет несоразмерные размеры кнопок.

В чём может быть проблема? Может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

**Как отображается в Chrome**

[image]

**Как отображается в webView**

[image]

**Сам код для webView**

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wev_view, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(address);

    try {
        Method m = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setMixedContentMode", int.class);
        if ( m == null ) {
            Log.e("WebSettings", "Error getting setMixedContentMode method");
        }
        else {
            m.invoke(webView.getSettings(), 2); // 2 = MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
            Log.i("WebSettings", "Successfully set MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("WebSettings", "Error calling setMixedContentMode: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(activity, WebViewFragment.this));
    webView.loadUrl(builder.toString());
    address2 = builder.toString();
    return view;
}
```

**Код WebViewClient**

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

AppCompatActivity activity;
RefreshWebView listener;

public MyWebViewClient(AppCompatActivity activity, RefreshWebView listener){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listener = listener;
}

public MyWebViewClient(AppCompatActivity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); попробуйте выставить

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, строки не помогли. Я поставил их после строки `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: Если вам просто показать Web-ресурс, используйте Chrome custom tabs вместо WebView. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja мне бы на webView попробовать это исправить.. Chrome custom tabs - мной пока не изучен вообще